# Notification Icon From Chrome

Tags: android, webview, responsive

I'm building an app that uses WebView to display my website since it has been built responsive. However my website plays music. When the screen goes off and the user turns it back on, I wanted it to show the notification bar like chrome does with pause, but also have a skip button. It's weird because in my car hooked to the radio the bluetooth skip button skips it, but there is no icon on the notification bar for the user to click. I'm not sure where to begin on this. Any useful information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this doc : http://sapandiwakar.in/android-media-player-lock-screen/

Comment: Thank you very much